# How to launch all azure webapps in a browser using Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

I'm trying to get the urls of all webapps/sites on my azure account and launch them in Internet Explorer.. I keep hitting the error:

```
Value does not fall within the expected range.
```

I'm sure I'm missing something small but just can't figure it out. please see code below.

```
$list = Get-AzureRmWebApp

foreach ($i in $list)
{
    $link = $list.DefaultHostName
    $Browser=new-object -com internetexplorer.application
    $Browser.navigate2($link, 0x1000 )
    $Browser.visible=$true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference **$i.DefaultHostName** in your foreach loop, not the entire **$list**.

```
$list = Get-AzureRmWebApp

foreach ($i in $list)
{
    $link = $i.DefaultHostName
    $Browser=new-object -com internetexplorer.application
    $Browser.navigate2($link, 0x1000 )
    $Browser.visible=$true
}
```